# Effectiveness of esterification catalysis's [Cu, Sulphuric acid, Acid Zeolite], in Whiskey distillation

Tags: organic-chemistry, food-chemistry, catalysis

If you go on a tour of a distillery, you will normally be told at some point how the (beautifully polished) copper pot stills <strike>catalyse the esterification of ethanol and higher (fusel) alcohols, with acids from the fermentation process</strike> improves the flavor of the whiskey. (And how *their* still geometry creates a superior product)

Obviously the distillation process, removing water and most of the higher (fusel) alcohols contributes to this as well.

How effective is Copper in that scenario? A still would not have more than say 100 m<sup>2</sup> of copper surface area and a batch load would be on the order of 5-50 thousand liters

How much more effective would using Sulphuric acid as a catalysis? (Obviously this would not be useful/food grade, but nice to know as a baseline)

Now (the much more interesting part) 
**How effective would Acid Zeolite be as a catalysis? Either as a distillation column packing medium, or adding a 'handful' to a barrel before leaving it to sit in a ware house for a couple of years/decades?**

Comment: Sulfuric acid would obviously be the best catalyst (when storing in barrels), mainly because it would be dissolved in the alcohol, while solid catalyst would require constant stirring/agitation. And a copper pot is a bad catalyst because of its low surface area.

Comment: @vapid Maybe, but it would not be very palatable :P & I would worry about what it might do to the barrel. Over the time scale of years I suspect (hope) normal Brownian mixing would be sufficient with Acid Zeolite. Good points though :D